# Отправка изображения с помощью AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Хочу отправить картинку AJAXом и получить её данные. Нужды пока в этом для себя не вижу, но стало интересно и пока что не получается. А конкретно мой код:

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Загрузить">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var form = document.forms.myform;
form.elements.button.onclick = function(){
    var file = form.elements.filename.files[0];
    if(file){
        img();
    }else{
        alert("Выберете файл.");
    }
}
function img(){
    var formdata = new FormData(form.elements[0]);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e){
        load.textContent = e.loaded + " / " + e.total;
    };
    xhr.open('POST', 'img.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    xhr.send(formdata);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.status != 200){
            alert("Status: " + xhr.status);
        }else{
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
print_r($_FILE['filename']['size']);
?>
```

**Файл вообще не передавался (понятное дело, отладка это показывала)**
А дело было из-за *FormData()* . Надо было передать с *append* , но он должен был работать и и так *FormData(аргумент)* .
После этого выдает:

`Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0
------WebKitFormBoundaryWmXgtD5Kn1xyTV8q Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="5f944a3ea1b8fcb56bd54f326666a04b.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿÛC...`

Но почему то не удается достать имя с $_FILES['filename']['name']. + выдает эту всю информацию только через php://input .

Comment: И что именно "пока что не получается"?

Comment: @D-side , если парсить php://input ом, то выводит _WebKitFormBoundary_**x**, **x** - n-ое кол-во рандомных чисел, если если $_FILES - то ничего. + уточнение: я пропустил в конце **PHP** кода букву "S" в глоб. перемен. "$_FILE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для парсинга не надо было ставить глобальной переменной кодировку.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/95480)

Comment: А какой еще ответ нужен? Убрал кодировку image/jpeg все заработала.